# Attaching onclick method to multiple canvas using a for loop

Tags: javascript, html, onclick

I need to add a onclick function to multiple canvas in a . I use a for loop to go through all the canvas and then add the onclick event with `attachEvent`.

I already tried with an eventlistener or directly adding the onclick event but nothing seems to work please let me know if you can see my mistake...

Here's my JavaScript code:

```
        //here's the loop where the canvas get their width, height and onclick 
        //event.
    function canvasSize() {
        var canvas=document.getElementsByTagName('canvas');
        var ctx;
        for (var i=0;i<canvas.length;i++) {
            canvas[i].width="50";
            canvas[i].height="50";
            ctx=canvas[i].getContext('2d');
            ctx.fillRect(0,0,50,50);
            ctx.fillStyle="blue";
            canvas[i].attachEvent("click", onClick(this,"voitures"));
        }
    };


         //onclick() function
    function onClick(elem,theme) {
        var images=preloadImages(theme);
        var canvas=getElementsByTagName("canvas");
        for (var i=0;i<canvas.length;i++) {
            if (canvas[i]==elem) {
                elem.drawImage(images[0],0,0)
            }
        }
    };

        //function where I preload every images
    function preloadImages(theme) {
        var tab=[];
        var imageObj= new Image();
        if (theme=="cars") {
            tab[0]="0.jpg"
            tab[1]="1.jpg"
            tab[2]="2.jpg"
            tab[3]="3.jpg"
            tab[4]="4.jpg"
            tab[5]="5.jpg"
            tab[6]="6.jpg"
            tab[7]="7.jpg"
            tab[8]="8.jpg"
            tab[9]="9.jpg"
            tab[10]="10.jpg"
            tab[11]="11.jpg"
            tab[12]="12.jpg"
        //...
        }

        for (var i=0;i<32;i++) {
            imageObj.src=tab[i];
            //imageObj.onload=alert("img "+i+" is loaded");
        }

        return tab;
    }
}
```

The code crash before adding the onclick function. Hope someone can help me find my mistake.

Comment: `attachEvent` is only available in IE, and you're invoking `onClick` instead of assigning a function as the handler.

Comment: And why on earth not  `for (var i=0;i<32;i++) { var imageObj = new Image();imageObj.src=i+".jpg" }` or if you want `var tab=[]; for (var i=0;i<32;i++) { tab[i] = new Image();tab[i].src=i+".jpg" }`

Comment: @martynas: There's no need to delegate events.

Comment: I can't use Jquery martynas. Thanks mplungjan... haha

Comment: Where am I using jQuery? or was that comment to martynas?

Comment: That was for martynas mp, What should I do if I can't use attachEvent... I already tried : canvas[i].onclick="onClick(..);" . Didn't work

Answer (score 0):

One: `attachEvent` is only available in IE.

Two: **DON'T** name functions `onClick` it's a reserved [global event handler](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers.onclick).

So to fix your `for` loop I would change your last line to this:

```
for (var i=0;i<canvas.length;i++) {
    var self = this;
    if(window.attachEvent){
        canvas[i].attachEvent("click", function(){
            newNameForOnClickFunction(self,  "voitures");
        }, false);
    }else{
         canvas[i].addEventListener("click", function(){
            newNameForOnClickFunction(self,  "voitures");
         }, false);
    }
}
```

I'm betting that you want to pass the canvis to your next function and not a refrence to your `canvasSize` function. If that's the case then you should pass `canvas[i]` instead of `this` (or `self` in my example above)

Comment: Hey, it doesn't crash anymore but it doesn't add the onclick event either. I also tried changing "this" to canvas[i].

Comment: @Charles did you change the name of your `onClick` function?

Comment: Yes, first thing I did